# Copia De Seguridad SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy haciendo una copia de seguridad automática, pero me marca error cuando se va a comprimir

```
declare @path2 varchar(200), @SQL varchar(500), @DBName varchar(100),@path varchar(100)

set @DBName = 'Almacen'

set @path = 'D:\Copia\'+ @DBName +'_' + convert(varchar,getdate(),112) + '.bak'

set @path2 = 'D:\Copia\'+ @DBName +'_' + convert(varchar,getdate(),112) + '.bak'

set @SQL = 'BACKUP DATABASE ['+@DBName+'] TO DISK = '''+ @path + ''' WITH
NOFORMAT,
INIT,
SKIP'
print (@SQL)
exec (@SQL)

DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(100), @COMMAND VARCHAR(500), @FILE VARCHAR(100)
SET @SERVER = @@SERVERNAME
SET @COMMAND ='"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\RAR"  a '+@path2+'.rar'+' '+@path+''

print (@COMMAND)
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL @COMMAND
```

**Este es el error**

> Un administrador del sistema puede habilitar el uso de 'xp_cmdshell'
>   mediante sp_configure. Para obtener más información acerca de cómo
>   habilitar 'xp_cmdshell', busque 'xp_cmdshell' en los Libros en
>   pantalla de SQL Server. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15281). No se pudo
>   realizar el paso.

Comment: Y que error te marca?

Comment: Será que el error es entonces de winrar y no de SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para corregir el error hay que utilizar una nueva consulta para habilitarla, las instrucciones son las siguientes:

```
--Permitir que las opciones avanzadas puedan ser cambiadas.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
--Permitir el uso de SP XP_CMDSHELL.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Si esto es información adicional ponlo en tu pregunta de lo contrario solo conseguirás que te den puntos menos

Comment: ¿Esto es una edición a la pregunta o es la publicación de la solución al problema?

Comment: solucion al problema